# Property 'createUserWithEmailAndPassword' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth'

Tags: typescript, firebase-authentication, angularfire2, angular9

I have got an error that Property 'createUserWithEmailAndPassword' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth'. Can you tell me what I will do?

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth) {}

  signUp(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Barun, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please provide what version of Angular and AngularFire are you using? This is because AngularFire v6.0 introduced a couple of breaking changes, including [`AngularFireAuth` now promise-proxying the underlying Firebase `auth.Auth` instance](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#angularfireauth).

Comment: According to your source, it seems you are using the correct format regarding the new release of AngularFire. Also, you can try  to re-install the angular fire module.'npm i @angular/fire'